# Logging broadcast Intents and manually trigger them (Android)

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

during my development in android I've missed a function that can log every broadcast intent that occur. Sometimes it had been very useful to have a function like that...

I'm also wondering how to trigger those broadcast intents manually on the emulator.

Is there an entire overview of available broadcast intents?

Would be great if someone would have some answers,

greets,
poeschlorn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> during my development in android I've
>   missed a function that can log every
>   broadcast intent that occur

They are logged to LogCat. Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to view them.

> I'm also wondering how to trigger
>   those broadcast intents manually on
>   the emulator

For the ones you are allowed to send, call `sendBroadcast()`. For system-generated ones, you generally cannot "trigger" them "manually".

> Is there an entire overview of
>   available broadcast intents?

Not really. Check out the documentation for Intent. All of the `ACTION_` strings whose comment says "Broadcast Action" are broadcast Intents. There are a few other scattered elsewhere in the system.

Comment: hi CommonsWare, I've already worked with logcat, but my issue was to expicitely have logging mechanism on broadcasts.

mh...it's a little bit sad that there's no entire overview of them...